# Check for specific text inside the children of an element

Tags: jquery, contains

I am trying to perform something based on a certain condition met. But the jquery code doesn't seem to be working.

HTML :

```
      <p class="Mycondition">
           <span><b>»</b></span>&nbsp;
           <span id="nav"><a href="#" id="lnkMycondition">Overview</a> 
              <span class="separator">
                 <b>»</b>
              </span>
           </span>
           <span><b>MyName</b></span>
        </p>


     <div class="prepend-1 span-22">
     <table class="hor" title="">
       <tbody>

             <tr>
                <td>abc</td><td>1</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('table').each(function () {

        if ($('#Mycondition').children(':contains("MyName")')) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: where are the `table`s and `tr`. Also `id`s are meant to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an ID selector for selecting an element by class name, also `children` returns a jQuery object that is always  `true`.

Try using `has` method:

```
$('table')
     .has('.Mycondition:has(:contains(MyName))') // filtering tables
     .find('tr:last') // finding last tr descendants 
     .addClass('Myclass'); // and adding classes
```

Or:

```
$('table').filter(function () {
    return $('.Mycondition', this)
                .children(':contains("MyName")').length;
}).find('tr:last').addClass('Myclass');
```

Update:

If you have several `Mycondition` elements and you want to add classes to their next siblings you can try:

```
$('p.Mycondition:has(:contains(MyName))') 
     .next('table') 
     .find('tr:last') // finding last tr descendants 
     .addClass('Myclass'); // and adding classes
```

---

```
$(function() {
    if ( $('p.Mycondition').children(':contains("MyName")').length ) {
        $('table').find('tr:last').addClass('myclass');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AH5KY/

Comment: the filter has to happen outside the table.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is if the children of "Mycondition" contain "MyName" Then  add a class to the last TR for all the tables on the page. There will be only one "Mycondition" on the page.

Comment: Thank u. When I inspect the element the myclass doesn't seem to be added to the TR

Comment: @BumbleBee Have you put the code within document ready handler?